# html5: Show an image OVER the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I was trying to implement the new `html5` `canvas` tag.

I made a Board for a game using that canvas. Now I wanted to add pawns to the game. I can add an image to canvas using `ctx.drawImage()` method of canvas, but that actually prints the image on the canvas.

I wanted the pawn to be drawn **over** the board (theoretically like a layer on it) so that I can move it. I tried this code to add an image using just javascript.

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = src;
img.width = width;
img.height = height;
img.alt = alt;

document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

But that didnt help. I can guess that this function just "adds" an element to the body of the main `html` file and that could be the reason why the image is not shown on the page.

Can anybody help me know how can draw an image **over** the canvas? Any help will be appreciated!

*Feel free to suggest edits.*

Comment: You likely need to set the css z value. It defines the staking order.

Comment: check the z-index of both elements, probably the pawn is being drawn below the canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use two canvases, with absolute positions, where one canvas is over the other canvas, e.g.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
 <canvas id="layer1" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
 <canvas id="layer2" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

in layer 1 you can show board, and in layer2 you can show pawns..

Comment: lage to chhe aa chalvu joi a. :P Let me check.

Comment: @SrujanBarai: are barai bhai aatli rate kaam karo chho, sui jaao :D

Comment: @SrujanBarai : freelancing karo chho?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114436/discussion-between-srujan-barai-and-parag-bhayani).